# Retain vs Assign for controls inside NIB/XIB using the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios4, interface-builder, xib

I'm using Interface Builder to build my rootViewController, which is retained by my application delegate. I have a few controls in this XIB such as a couple UIButtons, a UISlider, etc. as IBOutlets, hooked up properly in Interface Builder.

On the code implementation side of the XIB, I've seen some people use:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
    ...
}

@property(nonatomic, assign) UIButton *button1;
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIButton *button2;

@end
```

Why do they use assign instead of retain? I've seen some people not even use an assign property.

Is it pointless to use retain since the rootViewController's XIB will always contain a reference to them as long as it is loaded? Or are they just being lazy and not going through the steps to retain, synthesize & dealloc? Seems to me like it can't hurt to keep a reference around as long as the control is needed and the viewController hasn't been dealloc'ed, but just wondering if XIB's do something differently where this wouldn't be necessary.

I've read the memory management guide, btw.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cant hurt to keep all subviews as assigned instead of retained as long as they stay a child from there superview.

When you remove it from its superview and want to add it as a subview later on in your code. Thats not possible. When you remove it from its super its retain count will probably turn to zero. Thats one of the reasons why you use retain. Your controller object will then always be a owner of the view object.

I cant think of other reasons you **must** use retain instead of assign.

I always use retain, i think its a best practice for outlets and it seems to be a convention.

Comment: Thanks, just found someone else with the exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112486/really-best-practice-to-retain-iboutlet-view-elements - I liked the comment "you retain what you care about, not hope that someone else is retaining it for you." :) I guess the use of "assign" in the code examples I'd seen were just due to the examples being very simple. Anyway, thanks again.